# How to join all csv files in a folder with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I currently have multiple csv files in a folder, each has the following structure:

column1, column2

x1, y1

x2, y2

...

where column 1 is the same amongst all csv files. I am trying to join all csv files in the folder on column 1. And to identify the origins of every column 2 in the output csv, rename the new column (column2) by its filename. I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish it in python?

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do it. The csv module and pandas are both good options. Give it a try and report back if you have problems.

Comment: @tdelaney, I have been searching for methods, yet most of the resources online are for concating the file instead of joining them. I am kinda new to python. I know how to merge two dataframes, but not for hundreds of files in a folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it should solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in os.listdir(dir_name):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        curr_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir_name, filename))
        
        # In case this is the first df, then add the common column
        if df.empty:
            column1_header = list(curr_df.columns)[0]
            df[column1_header] = curr_df[column1_header]

        df[filename] = curr_df.iloc[:, 1]
```

Comment: @Gin Your'e welcome! in case this answer was helpful for you, you can vote up for it